# Show tootip and select pie slice on legend click of pie chart in HighCharts

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, function, highcharts

hi friends i want to show tooltip with legend on mousehover and click event of pie chart as same as when we hover pie slices and i want to show the pie selected (pie slice slide out like on pie point select )

this is default chart where i have disabled legend click for pie

```
  http://jsfiddle.net/LQS48/1/
```

can any one tell me how to do it

somthing like this as you see here

```
http://livecoding.io/3433043 ( which is done with custom buttons i want to achive this with highcharts legends
```

any help will be appreciated .. :)

**Update - Soltuion I founf with the help of steve and sebastian integrated here below in fiddle**

```
http://jsfiddle.net/8T7Ew/1/
```

**Final Update - Fixed a bug in this Soltuion I found with the help of steve and sebastian and highcharts support team  integrated here below in fiddle and working flawlessly now .**

well i hope this becomes a highcharts feature though ,

```
  Final working Solution for me :: http://jsfiddle.net/8T7Ew/3/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For click event on the legend, you can add:

```
   this.select();
   chart.tooltip.refresh(this);
```

to your legendItemClick function. http://jsfiddle.net/8T7Ew/.

For mouseover, there was a discussion on the highcharts forum http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=7094. The second page suggested this: http://jsfiddle.net/hfrntt/ArmRM/11661/

Comment: ur first answer solved half of my problem  and with your second answer hint on how do it with the help of my friend i finally solved it :)

Comment: hi stevep its working but am facing issue of tooltip firing on all chart as you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/8T7Ew/2/

Comment: You need to make your jquery selector more specific. e.g. for the last chart, use:
$('#piecontainer267 .highcharts-legend span, #piecontainer267 .highcharts-legend tspan').each(function(index, element) {

Answer (score 1):

Take look at example which introduced how display tooltip when you hover on legend http://jsfiddle.net/ArmRM/14892/

```
$('.highcharts-legend span, .highcharts-legend tspan').each(function(index, element) {
$(element).hover(function() {
    chart.tooltip.refresh(chart.series[0].data[index]);
},function() {
    chart.tooltip.hide();
})
```

});

Comment: thanks sebastian steve also recomeded to me . i have it working now thanks . just has small issue beacuse i am having multiple pie charts i am getting some strange console messages like "TypeError: a[0] is undefined Reload the page to get source for: http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js" for every other instance of my pie chart in console log . piecharts works fine though :)

Comment: It is possible to reproduce it is jsfiddle.net?

Comment: hi i am facing another problem this is the fiddle with the problem http://jsfiddle.net/8T7Ew/2/ when i hover the legend the other charts tooltip also show up has you can see on my fiddle . how can i show tooltip over the legend with concerned chart only :(